# при создании темы для Word Press не работает файл functions.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Хочу натянуть тему на WP, но ничего не выходит.
Добавил в тему файлы структура такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разделил `header и footer в index.php` добавил функции `<?php get_header(); ?>,<?php get_footer(); ?>.`
Эти части подключаются прекрасно.
Как только начал подключать `functions.php` всё как будто заклинило ничего не работает.
Пытаюсь подключить стили НОЛЬ.
Стили подключаю так, что бы проверить работает или нет эта связь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В файле `style.css` прописал фон для

```
body{
background:red;
}
```

в файле `functions.php` указал одну функцию:

```
'''
    <?php
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function (){
        wp_enqueue_style('style-name', get_stylesheet_uri());
        // wp_enqueue_script('script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    });
    ?>

'''
```

проверил его даже в валидаторе - ошибок синтаксиса нету.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на самом шаблоне фон не появляется и свойств body не добавляется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю, почему у меня не подгружаются стили?

Добавил в:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function ()
```

Вместо `wp_enqueue_scripts` добавил `after_setup_theme`, теперь, когда выбираю в админ панеле тему, то админка перекрашивается в красный цвет, а в самом шаблоне ничего не происходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С functions.php у вас всё нормально.
Вызовите внутри header.php функцию `wp_head();`, иначе событие `wp_enqueue_scripts` не сработает

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Все заработало!!!!